# Is there a way to filter out search results from a chosen jquery select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am hiding a particular option from chosen dropdown. I cannot remove it tout court because I need that option on IE6 (!).

The problem that I have is that when I start typing in the input field that hidden option reappears among chosen search results.

I also tried to use the {`display_disabled_options: false`} option but it is not working (maybe because I am disabling the option after chosen has already been initialized.

I am trying to do this:

```
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      display_disabled_options: false
    }).each(function () {
      $(this).on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function (event, params) {
        $('li:contains("whatever")').attr('disabled', true);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update the list after chosen initialization you need to trigger its update using `trigger("chosen:updated")`.

So use the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.chzn-select').chosen({
        display_disabled_options: false
    }).each(function () {
        $(this).on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function (event, params) {
            $('option:contains("shop")',$(this)).attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    });;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NfvBj/

Comment: Thanks. it works perfectly. One side question: why you added a second argument to jquery selection ($(this)) call?

Comment: @eolo999 you are welcome! The second argument is used to provide a context to the selector in this case it will search only on option element in the context of the current select, see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context